Clarification on Travel Requirements: Italy to Germany via Switzerland
I am an Indian citizen. Currently I am staying in Italy with a long-term visa.
The details of my visa is: Italian visa, D-type (research visa), Multiple entry.
I have applied for a residence permit and yet to receive it (I have a receipt from the post-office that I have applied for residence permit). I want to visit Germany and I have to travel through Switzerland. I want to travel using the FLIX bus.
Now, my queries are:

Can I travel to Switzerland with my passport, visa and receipt from the post-office?
Can I travel from Italy to Germany by flight without a residence permit card?

Looking forward to your suggestion.

Has your visa expired already? If it is still valid, the rest shouldn't matter.

No, it is not expired.

if you wanted to avoid Switzerland for whatever reason, you could take a train route via Austria instead

All three countries are part of the Schengen Area. A valid D visa from any Schengen Area country allows you to travel to any other Schengen country for up to 90 days in any 180 days period.
So you can indeed travel to Switzerland, Germany, and back.
It’s quite likely that in many cases you won’t even be checked (in theory there should be no checks at all, but “temporarily reintroduced” checks are all the rage these days).

Switzerland does carry out many border controls. It is after all an EU border where goods have to be declared, taxes have to be paid. I live practically on the Swiss border and even though they always let me through when I walk or cycle, they check many cars and regularly even stop the cross-border city bus to ask everyone for their passports.

Similarly, Swiss border guards will generally board your train to check passengers' papers who are about to enter Switzerland

Switzerland has always been doing frequent checks at land borders; to avoid repercussions from the European Commission, they can hide behind the excuse of performing customs checks despite only occasionally asking about goods at all
